# Refactor with FILTERS and same condition in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, refactoring, newrelic

Any help for refactoring this query?
Thank you

```
SELECT filter(count(*), WHERE action='INIT_PMS' AND error IS TRUE AND manualSelected IS NOT NULL) AS 'Error',
  filter(count(*), WHERE action='INIT_PMS' AND error IS FALSE AND manualSelected IS NOT NULL) AS 'No Error',
  filter(count(*), WHERE action='INIT_PMS' AND error IS NOT NULL AND manualSelected IS NOT NULL) AS 'No Value'
FROM MyDatabase SINCE 4 MONTHS AGO TIMESERIES
```

Comment: Are you sure that query runs in MySQL?

Comment: It's in New Relic. My question is if it's possible to refactor the 3 filters

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: The `FILTER(COUNT(*)...)` is easy to rephrase using `COUNT(CASE...)`. However, you'll need to explain what `SINCE 4 MONTHS AGO TIMESERIES` mea.s

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the duplicate filters from each `filter()` clause and add it them as generic filters after the `FROM` like this:

```
SELECT filter(count(*), WHERE error IS TRUE) AS 'Error',
  filter(count(*), WHERE error IS FALSE) AS 'No Error',
  filter(count(*), WHERE error IS NOT NULL) AS 'No Value'
FROM MyDatabase where action='INIT_PMS' AND manualSelected IS NOT NULL SINCE 4 MONTHS AGO TIMESERIES
```

..or you probably could use `facet cases()` if you don't want many `SELECT` options:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MyDatabase where action='INIT_PMS' AND manualSelected IS NOT NULL facet cases(where error IS TRUE as 'Error', where error IS FALSE as 'No Error', where error IS NOT NULL as 'No Value') SINCE 4 MONTHS AGO TIMESERIES
```